# Issue with installing Ubuntu 14.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I used universal usb installer on a 8gb flash 
and booted ubuntu 14.1 
but when I try to install ubuntu 14.1 inside windows 8.1 it just reboots and does absolutely nothing.
My pc specs 
Intel core i5
4 gb ram
How can I dual boot both of them?

Comment: Did You Try Ubuntu 14.04 ? Did You Use unetbootin ? Did You Try Ubuntu 14.1 WithOut installi

Answer (score 0):

The question is mostly vague, not giving us most of the details of what the exact problem is. Here are some suggestions:

1. If you have a computer with Windows 8 pre-installed, chances are that you need to [disable secure boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot)
2. If you think you successfully installed it, but can't boot at all, try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: No it is not pre installed and no I couldn't install

Comment: I booted ubuntu and selected install ubuntu then when i choose install ubuntu inside windows 8 the computer reboots into windows

Comment: Do you meet with all of the [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)? If not, I recommend that you go use a lighter Ubuntu distribution, such as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net).

Comment: thx for ur help anyway